# Screen is flickering even when using doublebuffering

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

I am totally new in programming.
For my first programm I tried to make a small game in c with windows api.
the following code is a nearly working snake, (some bugs not fixed yet)
but i cant find a working solution to fix that flickering.
(I dont know double Buffering so I just took from here: [http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-272723.html][1]

```
// snake1.02.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "snake1.02.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#define ID_MYTIMER 1234567
#define ID_BERRY 1
#define SEGMENTSIZE 10

const WCHAR szClassName[] = L"Snake1.02";
HWND hWnd;
UINT myTimer;

struct point {
    int x, y;
};



point snake[500];



int dx = SEGMENTSIZE;  //Change direction l=l+1
int dy = 0;
int snakelength=3;
int highscore=0;
WCHAR nachricht[100];
int map[80][60]; //Wenn Bildschirmgröße angepasst wird, auch hier anpassen!!!



// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;

    // Initialize global strings
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    myTimer = SetTimer ( hWnd, ID_MYTIMER, 40, NULL );

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    KillTimer ( hWnd, myTimer );
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+2);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szClassName;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{


   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szClassName, szClassName, WS_OVERLAPPED,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   for(int i=snakelength; i>=0; i--){
   snake[i].x =100-(i*SEGMENTSIZE);
   snake[i].y=20;}

   for(int x=0; x<78;x++){
   map[x][0]=1;
   map[x][56]=1;


   }

   for(int y=0; y<57;y++){
    map[0][y]=1;
    map[78][y]=1;

   }


    map[50][70]=2;





   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    HDC memDC;
    HBITMAP hMemBmp;
    HBITMAP hOldBmp;


    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);                                //flimmerfrei
        hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 800, 600);
        hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hMemBmp);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

        for (int i = 0; i<=snakelength; i++) {
            Rectangle(memDC, snake[i].x,snake[i].y,snake[i].x+10,snake[i].y+10);
        }
        for (int y=0; y<60;y++){
        for (int x=0; x<80;x++){
            if(map[x][y]==1||map[x][y]==2){
        Rectangle(memDC,x*SEGMENTSIZE,y*SEGMENTSIZE,x*SEGMENTSIZE+SEGMENTSIZE,y*SEGMENTSIZE+SEGMENTSIZE);
            }}
        }
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 800, 600, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);


        SelectObject(memDC, hOldBmp);
        DeleteObject(hMemBmp);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case ID_MYTIMER:  {
            if (map[snake[0].x/10][snake[0].y/10]==1){              //crashcheck
                KillTimer ( hWnd, myTimer );
                wsprintf (nachricht,L"Game Over. Punktestand: %d",highscore);
                MessageBox(hWnd, (LPCWSTR)nachricht,L"Ende",0);
                }
            if (map[snake[0].x/10][snake[0].y/10]==2)               //grow
            {               
                for (int i = snakelength; i>0; i--) 
                {
                    snake[i].x = snake[i-1].x;
                    snake[i].y = snake[i-1].y;
                }
                snake[0].x = snake[1].x + dx;
                snake[0].y = snake[1].y + dy;
                map[snake[0].x/10][snake[0].y/10]=0;
                snakelength++;
                highscore+=10;

            }

            for (int i = snakelength; i>0; i--) {
                snake[i].x = snake[i-1].x;
                snake[i].y = snake[i-1].y;
            }
                snake[0].x = snake[1].x + dx;
                snake[0].y = snake[1].y + dy;   



            InvalidateRect(hWnd, 0,1);
            return 0;
            }
                          }
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN: {
        switch (wParam) {


            case VK_DOWN:{
                if(dy!=-SEGMENTSIZE){
                dy=SEGMENTSIZE;
                dx=0;
                }
                  }
            break;


            case VK_RIGHT:{
                if (dx!=-SEGMENTSIZE){
                dy=0;
                dx=SEGMENTSIZE;
                }
                  }
            break;
            case VK_UP:{
                if (dy!=SEGMENTSIZE){
                dy=-SEGMENTSIZE;
                dx=0;
                }
                  }
            break;
            case VK_LEFT:{
                if(dx!=SEGMENTSIZE){
                dy=0;
                dx=-SEGMENTSIZE;
                }
                }
                break;
            case VK_ESCAPE:{
                ExitProcess(0);
                  }
            break;
        }
        }
     break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add one case to your main switch statement in WndProc:

```
case WM_ERASEBKGND: 
    return TRUE;
```

Comment: To the OP: _AND_ read the docs. Kudos for trying to leap into the Windows API with little programming knowledge, but you're not going to understand how to fix something if you don't even understand _why_ you're doing something in the first place.